# How to give exact responce to input json object in php?

Tags: php, json

The below code returns the format what i need, but it doesn't work dynamically,means if the user don't want the "id" then also it returns the "id" value. For better understanding i will show my input json object, in which user requests the fields what he required.
This is input json

```
Input:
{
"session_id": "cj9f28hf29",
"post_id": "91024",
"fields": "id, image_urls, tagged_users, has_liked, has_commented" 
 }
```

i have to check the "fields" key and return the requested fields only.
This is my code what i had written, can anyone please help me to make it dynamic.

```
            while ($row = $get_postid->fetch_array())
            {
                $id=$row['post_id'];
                $image_urls=explode(',',$row['post_image_url']);
                $storetag= explode(',',$row['post_tagged_id']);   
                $has_liked="false";
                $has_commented="false";
            }

            for($i=0;$i<count($storetag);$i++)
            {

                $user=mysqli_query($con,"select user_id, profile_image_url from Wheel_User where user_id='$storetag[$i]'");

                if(mysqli_num_rows($user)==0)
                {
                    //For failure status if session id is wrong.
                    http_response_code(500);
                    echo json_encode(array("error_code"=>"500","error_message"=>"Sorry, post id does not exists.".die()));
                }

                else
                {

                    while ($row = $user->fetch_array())
                    {

                        $tagged_users[$i]['id']=$row['user_id'];
                        $pro_image_url[$i]=$row['profile_image_url'];
                        $short_image_url[$i]=str_replace('_b','_t',$pro_image_url[$i]);
                        $short_image_url[$i]=str_replace('/images/','/thumbnails/',$short_image_url[$i]);
                        $tagged_users[$i]['short_image_url']=$short_image_url[$i];

                    }
                }  
            }


        echo str_replace('\/','/', json_encode(array("id"=>$id,"image_urls"=>$image_urls,"tagged_users"=>$tagged_users,"has_liked"=> $has_liked,"has_commented"=>$has_commented)));

        }
    }
}
```

And i hard code the key name in the output of json for ex:"id"=> but it has to be dynamic. please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to refactor the input JSON to an array more like

```
{
   "foo":"bar",
   "fields":['id', 'image_urls', 'tagged_users', 'has_liked', 'has_commented']
}
```

then you might be able to do something like

```
rowFields = ["id","profile_image_url"]
shortFields=["shortImageUrl"]


for $j = 0; j< $input.fields.count();j++{
   if(in_array(fields[$j],rowFields)){
      $tagged_users[$i][fields[$j]]=$row[fields[$j]];    
   } else {
      if(in_array(fields[$j],shortFields)){
        $tagged_users[$j][fields[$j]]=$short_image_url[fields[$j]];
      }
   }
}
```

Very much top of my head, but hope you get the gist!

Would have thought you can repeat this pattern for as many separate tables you need to pull data from.

Comment: yea i got it but i am fetching the data from two different db tables

Comment: Thank you, i can place that input JSON (fields) in an array. But i am confused how to implement that in my code.